# Problem with changing order of parameters in a SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Adding a new parameter between parameters or reordering parameters in a ssrs report breaks it.

Using text only, can't upload any images... (Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server)

I created a report that works using the cube "Analysis Services Tutorial".

- Parameters: City, State-Province.
- Table: State Province, City, Internet Sales Count

This report works fine, but when I change the order of parameters to:

- State-Province, City

Then I get that error when previewing the report:

> An error has occurred during report processing.
> The Value expression for the query parameter 'CustomerCity' contains an error: The expression references the parameter 'CustomerCity', which does not exist in the Parameters collection. Letters in the names of parameters must use the correct case.

One solution that I currently see is modifying the content of the rdl-file.
Hope anyone has any other ideas/solutions what I can do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah well only need to change the order of the parameters in the DataSet and with the context menu on right click I can also move the parameter up/down.